# How to update table with shared text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My table called "Cars" has these records

```
ID         Name
TOY        NULL
TOY938     Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 86KM
TOY492     Toyota Sendan Grey 2014 63KM
TOY297     Toyota Sendan Grey 2018 33KM
TOY882     Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 93KM
HON        NULL
HON362     HONDA CIVIC Blue 2009 70KM
HON932     HONDA CIVIC Yellow 2019 28KM
HON444     HONDA CIVIC White 2020 13KM
FOR        NULL
FOR882     FORD Mustang Black 2004 128KM
FOR727     FORD Black 2008 99KM
MAZ        NULL
MAZ457     MAZDA 3 Red in good condition
MAZ123     MAZDA 3 Red 88KM 
MAZ874     MAZDA 3 Red 2018
```

In my query all IDs with 3 chars have Null Names

What I want is to fill these nulls with most common words in its sub-category

for TOY

```
TOY938     Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 86KM
TOY492     Toyota Sendan Grey 2014 63KM
TOY297     Toyota Sendan Grey 2018 33KM
TOY882     Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 93KM
```

They all share the **"Toyota Sendan Grey"**

Therefor TOY should have **Name = Toyota Sendan Grey**

for HON, **Name = HONDA CIVIC**

for FOR, **Name = FORD**

for MAZ, **Name = MAZDA 3 Red**

I tried doing that but could not find the common words

I did this

```
UPDATE A
SET Name = LEFT(B.Name, ?????) -- Dont know how to find this number of shared letters
FROM Cars A INNER JOIN Cars B ON A.ID = Left(B.ID,3)
```

**Edit :**

This is a once off table. once data gets updated it will be used as a datasource for some process and will not be having other tables linked to it or any new records going to be inserted

Comment: This looks like you have normalisation issues. Make, Model, Colour, Year, and Milage should all be different columns.

Comment: this is not for a system, it is a single table and this is just a simulation of the problem that i have, the table is for totally different industry . i just used this example to make it easier to understand

Comment: Then give us representative sample data.

Comment: the data i supplied should be enough to explain the problem

Comment: Also, why is `'Maz'` only `'MAZDA 3'` when every row starts with `'MAZDA 3 Red '`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how large the table is, because that might be causing some performance issues.  But otherwise something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @maxLength as int;

select @maxLength = max(len(name)) FROM cars ;

WITH CTE_chars
as
(
    SELECT 1 as c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c+1 as c
    FROM CTE_chars
    WHERE c <= @maxLength
),

CTE_result
AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(id,3) id,cn.c as length,LEFT(ca.name,cn.c) as namePart,count(*) as matches
    FROM cars ca
    JOIN CTE_chars cn
        ON cn.c<= LEN(ca.name)
    WHERE LEN(ID)>3
    AND substring(ca.name+' ',cn.c,1)=' '
    GROUP BY LEFT(id,3),cn.c,LEFT(ca.name,cn.c)
)
,
CTE_rn
as
(
    SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by id order by matches desc,length desc) as rn
    FROM CTE_Result
)

UPDATE c
SET name = r.namePart
FROM CTE_rn r
JOIN cars c
    ON c.id = r.id
WHERE r.rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution splits the car name based on spaces and compares the count to the (settable) variable @num_of_word_repeats.  To preserve the ordering of words the CHARINDEX function is used as per this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/string-split-and-ordered-results/233480.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Cars;
GO
CREATE TABLE #Cars
(ID     CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 [Name] VARCHAR(200) NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO #Cars
(ID, 
 [Name]
)
VALUES
('TOY', 
 NULL
),
('TOY938', 
 'Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 86KM'
),
('TOY492', 
 'Toyota Sendan Grey 2014 63KM'
),
('TOY297', 
 'Toyota Sendan Grey 2018 33KM'
),
('TOY882', 
 'Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 93KM'
),
('HON', 
 NULL
),
('HON362', 
 'HONDA CIVIC Blue 2009 70KM'
),
('HON932', 
 'HONDA CIVIC Yellow 2019 28KM'
),
('HON444', 
 'HONDA CIVIC White 2020 13KM'
),
('FOR', 
 NULL
),
('FOR882', 
 'FORD Mustang Black 2004 128KM'
),
('FOR727', 
 'FORD Black 2008 99KM'
),
('MAZ', 
 NULL
),
('MAZ457', 
 'MAZDA 3 Red in good condition'
),
('MAZ123', 
 'MAZDA 3 Red 88KM '
),
('MAZ874', 
 'MAZDA 3 Red 2018'
);

DECLARE @num_of_word_repeats INT= 2, @added_delimitter CHAR(1)= ' ';

WITH split_cte(ID, 
               ID3, 
               split_str, 
               word_order_index)
     AS (SELECT c.ID, 
                LEFT(c.ID, 3), 
                sp.[value], 
                CHARINDEX(@added_delimitter + sp.[value] + @added_delimitter, @added_delimitter + c.[Name] + @added_delimitter)
         FROM #Cars c
              CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c.[Name], ' ') sp),
     count_cte(ID3, 
               split_str, 
               min_word_order_index)
     AS (SELECT id3, 
                split_str, 
                MIN(word_order_index)
         FROM split_cte
         GROUP BY id3, 
                  split_str
         HAVING COUNT(*) >= @num_of_word_repeats),
     cars_cte(id3, 
              generic_car_name)
     AS (SELECT id3, 
                STRING_AGG(split_str, ' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY min_word_order_index)
         FROM count_cte
         GROUP BY id3)
     UPDATE c
       SET 
           [Name] = cc.generic_car_name
     FROM #Cars c
          JOIN cars_cte cc ON c.ID = cc.id3
     WHERE c.[Name] IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM #Cars;

/* RESULTS *//*
ID  Name
TOY         Toyota Sendan Grey 2012
TOY938      Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 86KM
TOY492      Toyota Sendan Grey 2014 63KM
TOY297      Toyota Sendan Grey 2018 33KM
TOY882      Toyota Sendan Grey 2012 93KM
HON         HONDA CIVIC
HON362      HONDA CIVIC Blue 2009 70KM
HON932      HONDA CIVIC Yellow 2019 28KM
HON444      HONDA CIVIC White 2020 13KM
FOR         FORD Black
FOR882      FORD Mustang Black 2004 128KM
FOR727      FORD Black 2008 99KM
MAZ         MAZDA 3 Red
MAZ457      MAZDA 3 Red in good condition
MAZ123      MAZDA 3 Red 88KM 
MAZ874      MAZDA 3 Red 2018
*/
```